# Mysql tree with meta data in parent nodes

Tags: php, mysql, tree

so I have my data in a mysql database as a tree where the rows are connected to each other by parent_ID and a parent can have more than one child but a child can only have one parent.

not I've added a variable to the name the child nodes.
let's say a node has 5 child nodes I want to name those "widgets" and I store that string in the parent node.

but since children can contain their own groups of child nodes, I'm not sure how to handle this.

What I want to do is show a list of all group titles under a parent node

so here's a demonstration

```
parent1[group_title="title"]
    child1[group_title="sometitle"]
        child6[group_title="some_other_title"]
            child9
            child10
        child7
        child8
    child2
    child3
parent2[group_title="any given title]
    child5
    ...
```

I'd like to be able to get all titles onder a given node, so let's say I give parent1 I'd like to get

```
* title
* sometitle
* some_other_title
```

is this even possible?

Comment: since you are talking about a recursive tree that might have an arbitrary depth and mysql can not do recursive joins it is only possible if you do multiple queries scriptwise

Comment: http://www.edutech.ch/contribution/nstrees/index.php

Comment: so the only way to get this right is to loop through all the child nodes and collect the data? I was kinda hoping there  was a way to do this through a sql procedure maybe...

Comment: See the Answer. BTW why don't you accept any (the only one you got) answer?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive queries are not possible in standard SQL.

I had similar problem. This http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nestedset helped me.